# Cannot run Main class in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following project structure

```
-ProjectRoot
---src
------Main
------examples
---libs
```

My `src` folder is marked as `sources` in Intellij.

Now, when I want to run Main class, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
      }
    }
```

It doesn't have any package statements.

Comment: Typically IntelliJ uses `src/main/java/` as the source folder. Does `Main` mean `Main.java` or `Main`, the directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean the project, edit run configuration, choose the main class manually again. This probably wouldn't be needed if you had `src/main/java` structure.

Comment: Could also try just creating a new project and copy&paste old src files to it.

Comment: Yes, in this case yes, but in the future, when someone comes here with same problem with huge project, he won't :)