# cannot select main class in intellij run config

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I created a default kotlin project in intellij CE 2020.1 (latest).

1. File->New Project
2. Selected Java, Project SDK 14 (java version 14.0.1), Kotlin/JVM
3. Project src root is MyProject
4. Project structure is MyProject->src->Main.kt

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

In Edit Configurations I try to select Main.kt's main and OK button is disabled.
[Cannot run Main class in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068285/cannot-run-main-class-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `edit > configurations > Main class` it should say `MainKt` (yes, one word, uppercased K). You can write it manually without browsing through project files.

Comment: Thank you; why do they a browsing feature if you can't use it?